# How to use sample_weights with 3D medical data, without model.fit(x=tf.data.Dataset) causing an error like can't squeeze the last dim

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow-datasets, semantic-segmentation

env:

```
python = 3.8.12  
tensorflow =  2.6.0.  
keras = 2.6.0
```

so the problem is that I am trying to train highly unbalanced data, so I tried to use `sample_weights` as part of `model.fit()`, but I always get the same error:

```
ValueError: Can not squeeze dim[4], expected a dimension of 1, got 4 for '{{node categorical_crossentropy/weighted_loss/Squeeze}} = Squeeze[T=DT_FLOAT, squeeze_dims=[-1]](Cast)' with input shapes: [?,48,48,80,4].
```

so this is the shape of the data, where the `y_s` were converted  using `tf.keras.utils.to_categorical`, where `num_classes = 4` :

```
x_train (54, 48, 48, 80)  
y_train (54, 48, 48, 80, 4)   
x_test (18, 48, 48, 80)  
y_test (18, 48, 48, 80, 4)  
x_val (18, 48, 48, 80)   
y_val (18, 48, 48, 80, 4)
```

the architecture is `U-NET`:

```
inputs = Input((number_of_layers, height, width, 1))  
c1 = Conv3D(filters=16, kernel_size=3, activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same')(inputs)  
c1 = Dropout(0.1)(c1)
c1 = Conv3D(16, kernel_size=3, activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same')(c1)
p1 = MaxPooling3D(pool_size=2)(c1)
...............
...............
...............
outputs = Conv3D(num_classes, kernel_size=1, activation='softmax')(u9)
model = Model(inputs=[inputs], outputs=[outputs])
```

regarding the `compile` part, it's like the following:

```
model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'], sample_weight_mode="temporal")
```

NOTE: I'm not using `metrics=[‘accuracy’]` for evaluation, I'm using some `IOU`

The problem comes here, when I am using:

```
from sklearn.utils.class_weight import compute_sample_weight
weights = compute_sample_weight(class_weight='balanced', y=y_train.flatten())
weights = weights.reshape(y_train.shape)
weights.shape # => (54, 48, 48, 80, 4) (same as y_train)
```

so till here it's working, without any errors, but when I added `weights` to the following dataset:

```
tf_ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((x_train, y_train, weights)).batch(4)
```

and after that I tried to run `model.fit`:

```
model.fit(x=tf_ds, verbose=1, epochs=5, validation_data=(x_val, y_val))
```

I got the following error:

```
ValueError: Can not squeeze dim[4], expected a dimension of 1, got 4 for '{{node categorical_crossentropy/weighted_loss/Squeeze}} = Squeeze[T=DT_FLOAT, squeeze_dims=[-1]](Cast)' with input shapes: [?,48,48,80,4].
```

Any ideas, how to solve this ?

Comment: Have you tried: `model.fit(x=tf_ds, verbose=1, epochs=5, validation_data=(x_val, y_val), sample_weight=weights)` without feeding `weights` also to `tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices`

Comment: I need the ```sample_weight``` prarm, in order to balance the data, the ```model.fit()``` works without it, the main problem is with  the ```loss``` function, in the scenario above, I don't know how to solve it!

Comment: And I am assuming your labels are definitely one hot encoded, which is why you are using `categorical_crossentropy`? If they are not, then you could give `sparse_categorical_crossentropy` a try.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I removed the ```tf.keras.utils.to_categorical```, and changed the ```y_train``` to non categorical, everything went fine!
Could you please write that as an answer to accept it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming your labels are definitely one hot encoded, which is why you are using `categorical_crossentropy`? If they are not, then you could give `sparse_categorical_crossentropy` a try.